# jQuery deep copy with Ext JS?

Tags: object, extjs, extend, deep-copy

I've tried and surprised how could not I do with ExtJS. Let me explain with a code block.

In jQuery

```
console.clear();
var a = {
    b: 5,
    c: 4,
    o: {
        l: 2,
        p: 2
    }
}

var b = {
    k: 4,
    l: 3,
    c: 5,
    o: {
        m: 2,
        l: 1
    }
}

var ex = $.extend(true, a, b);
console.dir(ex)
```

Here is the output

```
ex = {
    a: {
        q: 2
    },
    b: 5,
    c: 5,
    o: {
        l: 1,
        p: 2,
        m: 2
    }
}
```

Ext apply, applyIf, copyTo does not worked like this. How can I produce the output in ExtJS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was writing an answer for your "Pageant and git don't remember my public keys and passphrase" question, pointing to http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx (see comment on 05-06-2009 9:38 AM): maybe that could have helped in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deep copying isn't supported in Ext. There are `Ext.apply` and `Ext.applyIf` but they both only work on the first level of a hash map and will override instead of merge any embedded arrays or hashes.

In fact the docs explicitly state that Ext.apply is meant to work on config objects, not that it matters but it's just to illustrate that it's not meant to be used as a merge utility function although it basically could if you only want to merge the first level/depth.

Comment: Yeah you are right, apply and applyIf do not do this case but I want be to sure. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 11):

For a recent project, we adapted [this sample code](http://javascript.about.com/od/objectorientedjavascript/a/oop17.htm) to produce the following method:

```
Ext.deepCopy = function(p, c) {
    c = c || (p.constructor === Array ? [] : {});
    for (var i in p) {
        if (typeof p[i] === 'object' && p[i] !== null) {
            c[i] = p[i].constructor === Array ? [] : {};
            Ext.deepCopy(p[i], c[i]);
        } else {
            c[i] = p[i];
        }
    }
    return c;
};
```

Comment: You will need an extra check for "null" valued objects because it fails when it tries to get "p[i].constructor". I changed the line to this: if (typeof p[i] === 'object' && p[i] != null)

Comment: @Cankut: Good catch!  It's so easy to forget that `typeof(null) === 'object'`.  I've updated my answer to include your fix, though I used `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: So, does this code copy object properties by value or by reference?

Comment: @user1186523: Objects and arrays are deep-copied, so they are copied by value.  Immutable types such as functions are copied by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Ext.Object.merge()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-merge) method, that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It does not clone array props: `a1 = { "a": [] }; a2 = Ext.Object.merge({}, a1); a1.a === a2.a` => true